# Dynamically provision global parent pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, parent-pom, maven-extension

How can one manage a common project parent `pom.xml` for multiple `github` organizations and projects, without continuously releasing it to some maven repository?

Answer (score 1):

Now there are two maven components for that:

- extension: [arkon-maven-extension](https://github.com/random-maven/arkon-maven-extension)
- plugin: [flatten-maven-plugin](https://github.com/random-maven/flatten-maven-plugin)

which can help resolve this issue.

Basic approach is to:

1. have single [arkon repository](https://github.com/random-maven/arkon) with parent `pom.xml`, which is *forever snapshot*, and never released anywhere
2. use [arkon-maven-extension](https://github.com/random-maven/arkon-maven-extension) to *auto magically provision* this parent pom into all projects which depend on it
3. use [flatten-maven-plugin](https://github.com/random-maven/flatten-maven-plugin) to *erase parent information* from the final project `pom.xml` used for deployment